# Every file opens the "Open With..." dialogue after updating mime types!

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, mime-type

Not only that, but the open with dialogue is empty!

[image]

This is my first question here, so if I made a mistake, please tell me!

Some info:
Kubuntu 15.04 (KDE/Openbox)

Comment: No, you didn't make a mistake by asking here. However, you give *very little* information. This makes it pretty hard to come up with a serious answer. As it  [is](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) described: "Provide details, share your research". What did you already try to solve this issue. The image you've supplied is ok, but it's still too little information. Your KDE/Openbox configuration seems to be a bit esoteric, (Google finds this combination mainly on Arch Linux) can you provide information how you did set it up?  And what type of computer is it, Laptop/Desktop, 32/64bit

Comment: Thank you, I'll try my best to keep the info relevant to this problem! I don't think the KDE/Openbox setup is the problem, I just installed openbox through apt-get. The problem might be with the Dolphin FM. This happened after I used `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`. I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall shared-mime-info` but that didn't work. I'm using a laptop. arch: 64 bit. I also tried to reinstall dolphin but that also didn't help.

Comment: I thought I fixed this problem by copying `/usr/share/mime` to `~/.local/share/mime`, but it didn't when I tried again, so I'm now stuck again...